# Unable to split data into correct array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call where im pulling user's selected colors and trying to stack the results in an array. I'm trying to stack colors by yeah and then months.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  var yr = element.created_date.slice(0, 4);
  var month = parseInt(element.created_date.slice(5,7));
  var color = element.colorvalue.split(",");

  if (counts[color] === undefined) {
    counts[color] = {};
  }
  if (counts[color][yr] === undefined) {
    counts[color][yr] = {};
  }

  current_value = counts[color][yr][month];
  if (current_value === undefined) {
    // Doesnt exist yet, so add it
    counts[color][yr][month] = 1;
  } else {
    // Exists, so increment by 1
    counts[color][yr][month] = current_value + 1;
  }
});
```

This is the output im getting from this:

```
{"red, blue, yellow":{"2015":{"8":1}},"blue, red":{"2015":{"8":1}},"red":{"2015":{"7":1,"8":2}},"yellow":{"2015":{"10":1}},"blue":{"2015":{"9":1}},"yellow, red, blue":{"2015":{"7":1}}}
```

I am using the .split(",") thinking that it would understand to seperate the colors into their own stack but it's not. This is what im expecting to return back.

```
{"red":{"2015":{"1":23,"2":19,"3":32,"4":18,"5":12,"6":22,"7":23,"8":21,"9":16,"10":23,"11":22,"12":14},"2016":{"1":19,"2":9}},"yellow":{"2015":{"9":1,"12":1},"2016":{"1":16,"2":3}},"blue":{"2015":{"11":1,"12":2},"2016":{"1":5,"2":1}}}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to show an example of what im trying to accomplish. Would anyone have any idea what im missing? https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/29/

Comment: where's the jsfiddle?

Comment: My bad here it is https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/29/

Comment: .split() returns an array, you should traverse through that array to get each color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split the colors, you end up with an array, you want to iterate over each individual color. Otherwise, since you're using the array as a property on an object, it becomes serialized into a string (which is basically undoing the split you just performed).
 https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/32/

```
var colors = element.colorvalue.split(",");

colors.forEach(function (color) {
  color = color.trim(); // remove any whitespace from the split
  // now you can do stuff
})
```

And that gives you

```
{
    "red": {
        "2015": {
            "7": 2,
            "8": 2,
            "9": 2
        }
    },
    "blue": {
        "2015": {
            "7": 2,
            "9": 2
        }
    },
    "yellow": {
        "2015": {
            "7": 1,
            "8": 1,
            "9": 1
        }
    }
}
```